# Raycast target not moving with parent even though rays function with a vector direction

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-4.0, raycasting

[Object facing left at the center of the scene, with the raycast cast with ray of transform.position, transform.forward](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKZ5n.png)

[Object facing left at the edge of the scene with the same ray, ray still casts to the same point even though the point is being called as a direction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Movdm.png)

How could this be happening? I've already rewritten the Raycast code a few times, but here is the current iteration:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RaycastTest : MonoBehaviour {

    //width will control the distance of the two rays' direction from each other
    //range will control the collision range
    public float width, range;
    //will take width and control bias in the furture
    float b;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update () {
        //loop from negative one to positive one to add left and right rays in the future
        for (int i = -1; i < 3; i += 2)
        {
            //commented line segment showing how bias will work to control the angle of the ray
            //! cant do any of that yet because this ray doesn't work
            Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, /*(transform.forward + transform.right/2 * i) / 3*/ transform.forward);
            RaycastHit hitInfo;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, out hitInfo, range))
            {
                Debug.DrawLine(ray.origin, hitInfo.point, Color.red);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.DrawLine(ray.origin, ray.direction * range, Color.green);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is probably either at line 24 or 27, but I still have no clue how its coming up.

EDIT: I tested this by setting the ray direction to a constant: (-1, 0, 0) (global left) and the issue persisted, so it is probably an issue with the Ray declaration in line 24.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add the transform to the debug.drawline in else